# Trying to put png images through an php include... How is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, include, png, dreamweaver

Im working on dreamweaver with php coded files, im using a Testing server located on my computer...

Im trying to add some png images but with the js 'swap' function, (an image that when the cursor is on top changes). But everytime i put on the include it shows an error message... I did an empty file where i put the images with the swap js function and its working in that empty page. This pictures with the swap are .png and have links that take you to different pages... They work... But When i put the include to call this pictures to, the pictures does not show.

In the main page where i want the include i put

```
     php include ("_includes/swaplinks.php")
```

But then i put it live it show an orange error message that says that the include cant be found... the error says "the path is not in the server" but its not true cause i checked and everything is in the server... Everything is correct...  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using full paths:

```
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/swaplinks.php' );
```